# Octal to Decimal converting with VB 6

Tags: math, vb6

I have heard about **octal** number system lately and i wanna learn about it.

My dumb teacher that i asked for it. Told me "its no more used, u dont need to learn" but no sire im pretty sure its still in use so i need to know!

If there is someone who can explain me the **octal** number system and show me a way to convert it to **Decimal**(number system that we use in life) "it would help me to learn about it a lot" and where i can use it in life so i can show smt to that dumb teacher that he is wrong, that he must do his job on teaching..

i wanna do it on vb6, cause my teacher works on vb6 usually.

Comment: What makes you "pretty sure it's still in use" ? Can't you show your teacher those examples?

Comment: Wikipedia has an article about that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal, found via a search engine named "Google"

Comment: @AakashM i ve seen lots of people talking & sharing knowledge about it all over the internet than i asked my teacher about what is this number system.. thats why im pretty sure its still in use cause people still asking about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get more about Octal from Wiki - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal
The octal, or base 8, number system is a common system used with computers. Because of its relationship with the binary system, it is useful in programming some types of computers.

Decimal, hexadecimal, and octal representations are straightforward. To read a string in these formats, use CLng.

```
Dim value As Long
value = CLng(Text1.Text)
```

Hexadecimal strings should begin with &H and octal strings should begin with &O.

To convert a value into a decimal, hexadecimal, or octal string representation, use Format$, Hex$, and Oct$ respectively. For example, Oct$(256) returns the octal representation of the value 256 (which is "400").

Comment: octal actually looks better than hex i dont really know why my teacher acted like that but i got my example now to show him the opposite. Thank you!

Comment: @BerkerYüceer: Out of interest, how does it look better? A byte is the smallest atomic unit in the PC architecture and as base 256 is impractical, the square root of that (base 16, hex) gives the easiest unit to work with.

Comment: @Deanna 
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal)
*It has the advantage of not requiring any extra symbols as digits (the hexadecimal system is base-16 and therefore needs six additional symbols beyond 0–9).
which means lesser numbers of symbols used to process, its like processing (3 types of aple instead of 3 types of apple + 3 types of orange) which is gonna give u increased processing speed to do the job. Thats what i understand at least.

Comment: also yes i know hex is providing an easy way but i like to use old stuff and it seems faster to me cause processing just 2 binary with one binary shows the next couple binary.

Comment: Also see the fact that octal needs 2 and 2/3 of a digit for each byte complicating things again :)